# What is the best way to validate XML against XML Schema, parsing it and storing data back to MySQL Database using Perl?

Tags: mysql, xml, perl

Currently I am working with XML and I want to know what would be best approach to validate XML against XML Schema, parse it and store it back to MySQL database using Perl ?

I think of XML::Xerces for parsing purpose but not sure if it's the right approach.

Note: I have very large XML file >1GB size.

Comment: I guess this is the third time you are asking how to store xml in a database. And you still don't provide any details. Do you want to store the xml itself in the db? Can you provide examples of your xml and your db schema?

Comment: I do not want to store direct XML into Database. I want to parse it and then store because XML coming from client side has data as well as decision rules and this decision rules need to go to ILOG JRules and data should go into MySQL Database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XML Xerces will match your needs. I am using it and i really like it.

In addition to your first edit:

Since your XMl File is very big you have to think of optimizing your parsing process since lot of memory and time can be used for that.

Found an nice small example to get started:

[XML Validation with Perl](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2000/11/08/perl/index.html)

Another Add:

If you dont want to write simple XML to your Database...it is important that you have an eye on your data, since your validation is outdated after you've written it to the Database in a different form. Be sure that you validate with a good scheme and some extra validators.
Large XML can be tricky sometimes.

Comment: Prepare to answer the next question in this unforgettable series: "How do I parse XML using XML::Xerces?"

Comment: you know each other Manni and Rachel? :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [XSD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Schema_%28W3C%29) to validate the XML and if you can format the XML into something MySQL can just import/insert. [Here is an example](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/xml-in-mysql5.1-6.0.html#xml-5.1-importing)